# Add space between headings and body in the home of the iPad app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

It's a pain in the ass for me to quit the app, draw a red circle in another app and return to the app, so...

[image]

If you notice the three questions in the bottom, you will notice that the emboldened headings (*New Answer, Comment*) are stick to the next character. Imperfect.

- App Version: 1.4.0.249
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next beta build.